# How to set a multilevel folder encryption?

Tags: encryption, ecryptfs, letsencrypt

**How to encrpyt folders multiple time with the number of encryption equal to the depth of the folder?**

In other words,if a folder is at depth 3 (contains in 2 other folder from the root) it should be recursively encrypted 3 times.

Say for instance I have the following filesystem

```
# tree
 .
└── L1-1
    └── L2-1
 └── L1-2
        └── L2-2
               └── L3-2
```

I want to encrypt `L1-1` and `L1-2` one time, `L2-1` and `L2-2` twice and `L3-2` 3 times.

PS: `encfs` is excluded since it is not reliable and `ecryptfs` may not work for recursive encryption (see [this post](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/329163/is-multiple-ecryptfs-encryption-possible))

Comment: Why would you want to do this? It really doesn't make your files any more secure.

Comment: For double encryption, in case the attacker has 2 keys protected by a password, the number of combination to be test for bruteforcing is N^2 instead of N for a simple encryption. Why are you saying it may not be more secured?

Comment: Because encryption methods are basically either good enough (not breakable in the lifetime of the universe) or not good enough (breakable). Re-encrypting doesn't make you more secure. Sort of like how two lines of unequal length both have infinite points.

Comment: As others have said, there's no point.  Also, you'd probably be better off using full-disk encryption rather than per-folder encryption, for a variety reasons (better usability; likely to be better security in practice, since you don't have to worry about temporary files sitting around unencrypted and other such issues).

Comment: I agree that multiple encryption does not make sense when seeing the data outside the OS, but within the OS it avoid to make the data available when being online. Example: a folder hierarchy with each folder associated to a more-and-more restrictive firewall as we go in depth.

Answer (score 0):

Sort your files in folders:
confidential; Secret; TopSecret; BurnBeforeReading.
Encrypt BurnBeforeReading with a big key or loong cryptic password!
Move this file into TopSecret and repeat with new key / password, and encryption algorithm and move this bigger file into Secret - redo operation and move the new by now Large file into the Confidential library - And encrypt!
If you are going to so much trouble, it would be a good idea to change language for each folder!

Now It resembles Russian dolls, each getting bigger to contain the previous - so use a big disk!

Comment: The solution is to set a hierarchically encrypted disk with LVM and LUKS and mount every partition hierarchically.

Comment: @j658063.mvrht.com  Amazing, and that is a standard solution -  how much is the overhead at level say 5?